# Close sockets of JeroMQ-Worker in MultiThreaded Execution

Tags: java, multithreading, zeromq, executorservice, jeromq

consider the following worker:

```
public class Worker implements Callable<String> ....
// initialize context
@Override
public String call() {
    ZMQ.Socket pullSocket = context.socket(ZMQ.PULL);
    pullSocket.connect(HOST_PULL_SOCKET);

    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !context.isClosed()) {

        String result = pullSocket.recvStr();
        return result;
    }

    return "test";
}
```

The `pullSocket.recvStr()` throws an `java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException` as the following scenario

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
List<Worker> workers = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0: i < 4;i++){
    workers.add(new Worker()); // Class where call() is executed
}
String result = service.invokeAny(workers);
```

is executed.

How can I avoid this kind of Exception or what is preferred way to handle the closing of sockets when`invokeAny()` gets called?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this exception because executor was shutdown or maybe there in some place of your program you have `System.exit()` call. In generalYou are getting this exception when thread  in which nio chanel was blocked, was interrupted. This is signal to stop processing of current task - make task responsible to this request - you can log, clear resources and exit the task. As i understand you are not expecting you worker thread to be interrupted - check you program code - and stop the interruption.